# Change unmatched rule action for main site - Azure Web App slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

[click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfZBs.png)I've been struggling to find anything on this topic for the past week and I have not seen anything, I don't believe Microsoft hasn't got the PowerShell code for it.

What I'm trying to do is add a bunch of IP access restrictions to an Azure Web App Slot [emphasis is on slot] I have a working script for the parent app. And Yes, I want to target the Web App slot with a different Pipeline.

This is the entire script:

```
param ($FrontendAppName, $backendAppName,$appResourceGroup, $Slot)
Write-Host "Frontend: " $FrontendAppName
Write-Host "Backend: " $backendAppName
Write-Host "ResourceGroup: " $appResourceGroup
Write-Host "Slot: " $Slot


Write-Host "Importing Az Modules"
#Import Azure Modules
Import-Module -Name Az.Websites
New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.IpSecurityRestriction


# This needs to be from the front end to the backend
Write-Host "Getting Frontend  web IPs ..."

$ipList = (Get-AzWebAppSlot -Name $FrontendAppName -Slot $Slot -ResourceGroupName $appResourceGroup).PossibleOutboundIpAddresses -split ","   
$webApp = Get-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $appResourceGroup -Name $backendAppName -Slot $Slot

Write-Host $ipList

Write-Host "Adding Frontend web IPs ..."
ForEach ($ip in $ipList) {
    $ipAddress = "$($ip)/32"
    $existingRule = $webApp.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions | Where-Object { $_.IpAddress -eq $ipAddress -and $_.Name -eq "FrontendAppName" }
    if ($null -eq $existingRule) {
        $rule = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.IpSecurityRestriction
        $rule.ipAddress = $ipAddress
        $rule.action = "Allow"
        $rule.priority = "10"
        $rule.name = "FrontendAppName"
        $webApp.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions.Add($rule)
    }
}

Write-Host "Adding Firewall IPs to backendapp Slot ..."

# Custom IPs [remove block comment and enable relevant IP addresses as desired]
$customIPs = @(
       # Generic integrations
      [pscustomobject]@{ruleName='RuleName1'; ipAddress='2.3.4.5/32'},
      [pscustomobject]@{ruleName='RuleName2'; ipAddress='6.7.8.9/32'},
      [pscustomobject]@{ruleName='RuleName3'; ipAddress='10.11.12.13/32'}
       )

ForEach ($customIP in $customIPs) {
    $existingRule = $webApp.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions | Where-Object { $_.IpAddress -eq $customIP.ipAddress -and $_.Name -eq $customIP.ruleName }
    if ($null -eq $existingRule) {
        $rule = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.IpSecurityRestriction
        $rule.ipAddress = $($customIP.ipAddress)
        $rule.action = "Allow"
        $rule.priority = "12"
        $rule.name = $($customIP.ruleName)
        $webApp.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions.Add($rule)
    }
}


Write-Host "Querying web app slot"
$Resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName rg-devops-dev -Name app-devops-dev-backend/F2 -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots 
$Resource.Properties.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction = "Deny"
$Resource | Set-AzResource -Force
```

## Write-Host "Saving back to webapp ..."

## $webApp | Set-AzWebAppSlot

I've put a placeholder for the slotname for obvious reasons

I get this error message:
##[error]The property 'IpSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

Thanks for your help in advance

I want to be able to have the unmatched rule action for the web app slot to be set to deny.

Answer (score 0):

> The property 'IpSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set: -

There is no `IpSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction`property available on the web app properties. In order to set the action to deny, you need to use the `$webApp.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions`.

Now `$webApp.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions` is an array contains a set of IP addresses and their relevant details. Traverse the array and set an `action` field to deny using `foreach` as shown below.

```bash
foreach ($customIP in $customIPs) {
    $existingRule = $webApp.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions | Where-Object { $_.IpAddress -eq $customIP.ipAddress -and $_.Name -eq $customIP.ruleName }
    if ($null -eq $existingRule) {
        $rule = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.IpSecurityRestriction
        $rule.ipAddress = $($customIP.ipAddress)
        $rule.action = "Allow"
        $rule.priority = "12"
        $rule.name = $($customIP.ruleName)
        $webApp.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions.Add($rule)
    }
}
foreach($iprestriction in $webApp.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions){
  $iprestriction.Action = "deny"
  }
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jahnavi
I appreciate your time on this. What I'm really after is this in the screenshot, to be able to have the Powershell script add all the custom IPs with allow action and set the unmatched rule action for the web app slot to deny for the main site. Not set the action to allow for each custom IP if that makes sense.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your requirement more for better understanding? what do you mean exactly for `unmatched rule action`. @SafeCyclistSafeCyclist

Comment: I can't seem to add a screen shot to explain what I mean, once I'm able to do that, you'll see. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I've added the screenshot to show what I'm trying to do, hope it clears things up. Thanks

Comment: Ok checking on it. @SafeCyclistSafeCyclist